# JHipster with MySQL back-end fails on first start with "table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin"

Tags: mysql, jhipster, liquibase

I'm getting the following error when I try to start a new JHipster app using MySQL as the database:

```
2019-07-30 09:55:40.583 ERROR 35895 --- [-service-task-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin. [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO compose.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, `DESCRIPTION`, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES ('00000000000001', 'jhipster', 'config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml', NOW(), 1, '8:c5bfc567913b118109a43e981cd02883', 'createTable tableName=jhi_user; createTable tableName=jhi_authority; createTable tableName=jhi_user_authority; addPrimaryKey tableName=jhi_user_authority; addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName=jhi_user_authority, constraintName=fk_authority_name, ...', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.6.3', '4491329886')]

liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin. [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO compose.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, `DESCRIPTION`, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES ('00000000000001', 'jhipster', 'config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml', NOW(), 1, '8:c5bfc567913b118109a43e981cd02883', 'createTable tableName=jhi_user; createTable tableName=jhi_authority; createTable tableName=jhi_user_authority; addPrimaryKey tableName=jhi_user_authority; addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName=jhi_user_authority, constraintName=fk_authority_name, ...', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.6.3', '4491329886')]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:356)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:57)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:125)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:109)
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.setExecType(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:384)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.markChangeSetExecStatus(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1086)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:64)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:305)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:119)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:352)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

It looks like it's failing on a liquibase step. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liquibase does not create the *DATABASECHANGELOG* table with the required primary key. Try stopping JHipster, running the following SQL commands against your mysql database, and then restarting JHipster:

```
ALTER TABLE DATABASECHANGELOG
ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);

drop table jhi_persistent_audit_evt_data;

drop table jhi_persistent_audit_event;

drop table jhi_user_authority;

drop table jhi_authority;

drop table jhi_user;
```

That should resolve the issue.